# Printed key and values from a Javascript object is duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON object in the following format

```
var myarray = {
  "2020-01-20": ["08:00 - 09:00", "09:00 - 10:00"],
  "2020-01-21": ["08:00 - 09:00"]
};
```

What I want to do is to print a list with the key following each value of the list. Expected outcome is

```
2020-01-20 | 08:00 - 09:00
2020-01-20 | 09:00 - 10:00
2020-01-21 | 08:00 - 09:00
```

I try to do this with the following code, but I have an unexpected behaviour.

```
var entries = '';
$.each(myarray, function(key, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    entries += entries + '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';
  }
});
$('#entries').html(entries);
```

Where the outcome is

```
2020-01-20 | 08:00 - 09:00
2020-01-20 | 08:00 - 09:00
2020-01-20 | 09:00 - 10:00
2020-01-20 | 08:00 - 09:00
2020-01-20 | 08:00 - 09:00
2020-01-20 | 09:00 - 10:00
2020-01-21 | 08:00 - 09:00
```

You can find a jsfiddle here with a [reproducable example](https://jsfiddle.net/arzg4vL0/1/)

Comment: change `entries += entries + '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';` to `entries += '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';`

Comment: You're adding entries twice

Comment: A working demo https://jsfiddle.net/ta0onv2c/

Comment: You need to do a minor fix in your code demo https://jsfiddle.net/arzg4vL0/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line inside the for cycle:

```
entries += entries + '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';
```

should be:

```
entries += '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';
```

It's clearly a typo in writing the code, with the correction your fiddle example will give:

```
2020-01-20 | 08:00 - 09:00
2020-01-20 | 09:00 - 10:00
2020-01-21 | 08:00 - 09:00
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I cannot believe it was such a bug in the code :P Thank you

Comment: It happens even worse, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

`entries += entries + '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';`

With this:

`entries += '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';`

You actually print the entries twice.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
var entries = '';
$.each(myarray, function(key, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    entries += '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';
  }
});
$('#entries').html(entries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
entries = entries + '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>'
```

or

```
entries += '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two types of addition assignment in a single line, which is why you are getting that output. If you replace `+=` with `=` or remove `entries +`  from that line, you will get your desired output.

The two possible corrections are below:

```
entries = entries + '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';
```

and

```
entries += '<div>' + key + ' | ' + value[i] + '</div>';
```